# Java Library or API for extracting tweets of particular interest

Tags: twitter, text-mining, java

I would like to know if there is a java library or API , that can extract tweets of my interest such as i want to know which tweets have reported about the strike in upcoming days in Islamabad city or bomb blast recently occured in my city . etc. I know there are other libraries out there but they only tell about whether the specific tweet is positive , negative or neutral. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every library for integrating twitter tweets to your application is based on the [twitter apis](https://dev.twitter.com).
For your specific example, you can try [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).
The process is really simple: just try from [here](https://twitter.com/search-home) your keywords to determine which keywords best suit your need and then use the actual API like [this](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Islamabad)(returns tweets with keyword:Islamabad) to return the tweets you need in a JSON format.
**NOTE:**
Version 1.1 of the APIS uses an OAuth [Authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)(I have not tried it yet  so I can not provide more details :( ).

Now for Java libraries(frameworks) that simplify this process, the only one I know is [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/). But in case you are not familiar with Spring framework in general, the best thing is to just read the Json url generated by the api and unmarshall it to get your results.